# Recreating 3D motion

Tags: data-visualization, 3d

Basically what I'll be doing is obtaining some g forces (acceleration due to gravity) from sensors (tri-axial accelerometer and gyroscope) and want to recreate the same motion on a graphical display. I've already worked out all the system of equations (or matrices) of motion to figure out the translation of the object (distance traveled with respect to time), so that is not an issue.  Also, this is not real-time, all the data will be stored and later evaluated.

**Which software should I use to recreate motion?**

I do most all my work in C#.net creating winforms. I've dabbled in Unity 3D, POV-Ray, and Web-GL when it comes to 3D graphics.  I have the best experience in Unity 3D, which I was planning on using for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Personally when it comes to 3D my go-to solution is [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) 3-D as it includes just about every facility that you can think of for 3-D and is free, *gratis & open source* plus cross platform.

It is also well worth looking at [VPython](https://www.blender.org/) which provides excellent 3-D simulation, without being as heavyweight as Blender, as well. Also free, *gratis & open source* plus cross platform.